# React with Redux app exceeded daily read allotment from firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I have an app built with React using Redux and thunk middleware. I was working with it all day and reached a daily limit of 50,000 reads from google firestore. Obviously, I didn't actually load a page 50,000 times so I am doing something wrong. Maybe I am not as adept at redux as I thought, but I have worked in ngrx with no problems like this.

I handle a typical page in react in the following manner:

- The top level component fore each page connects to the firestore in the manner shown below
- Children components receive data from parent components back to the parent
- 

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
            questions : state.firestore.ordered.questions ? state.firestore.ordered.questions : [],
            auth:state.firebase.auth,
            tags : state.firestore.ordered.tags ? state.firestore.ordered.tags : []
    }
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        {collection:'tags'},
        {collection:'questions'}
    ])
)(QuestionsPage);
```

I don't think that this is a problem with the config. I think that there are multiple reads happening each time a page is loaded and I don't understand why. Should I be using some sort of snapshot to prevent this? Would it help if I didn't have a connection but just did a read? If so, how much? Thanks.

Comment: Is this data being updated frequently? You might be listening to it's realtime updates and this could be causing you to exceed the limit.

Comment: The firstoreConnect command sets an observable on the data, but the data is not being changed regularly. Is that the issue? Is it doing regular reads? I thought that it would only update when there was a change.

Comment: Not really, you are correct in your assumption that it only reads when there is a change. At this point it might be a good idea to reach out to [Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing), so you can check what caused this much reads in your Firestore.